# Finding intersection of two geospatial vector data in shapefile format using Python and GeoPandas

Tags: geopandas, shapely

I have two geospatial shapefiles.

**1. The first one is a contour shapefile, generated via  following code**

```
rasterDs = gdal.Open('raster.tif')
rasterBand = rasterDs.GetRasterBand(1)
contourPath="contour.shp"
contourDs = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile").CreateDataSource(contourPath)

#define layer name and spatial 
contourShp = contourDs.CreateLayer('contour', proj)

#define fields of id and elev
fieldDef = ogr.FieldDefn("ID", ogr.OFTInteger)
contourShp.CreateField(fieldDef)
fieldDef = ogr.FieldDefn("elev", ogr.OFTReal)
contourShp.CreateField(fieldDef)

#The raster band is taken from the first cell
gdal.ContourGenerate(rasterBand, 12.5, 240, [], 1, 0., 
                     contourShp, 0, 1)

contourDs.Destroy()
```

**2. The second one is a path file, containing LineString and have been generated by following code**

```
import fiona
import pandas as pd

def generate_shp_file(line_csv, des_output):
    """
        Converting the final coordinates stored as csv to shapefile.
    """
    #import dataframe from csv file
    coordinate_df = pd.read_csv(line_csv, header = 0)

    # define schema
    schema = {
                'geometry':'LineString',
                'properties':[('Name', 'str')]
            }
    
    lineShp = fiona.open(des_output, mode = 'w', driver = 'ESRI Shapefile',
                         schema = schema, crs = "EPSG:4326")

    # Get the list of points
    coordinates = []
    rowName = ''
    for index, row in coordinate_df.iterrows():
        coordinates.append((row.Y,row.X))
        rowName = row.Name

    # Save record according to the subject of shapefile.
    rowDict = {
                    'geometry': {
                                    'type':'LineString',
                                    'coordinates': coordinates
                                },
                    'properties': {
                                    'Name' : rowName
                                },
              }
    lineShp.write(rowDict)
    lineShp.close()
```

line_csv file is a csv file which contains latitude and longitude under header X and Y respectively.

The task is to find the intersection points between the contour shapefile and path shapefile.

**I am using following code to do so**

```
import geopandas as gpd
import warnings
# Load contour and linestring shapefiles
contour = gpd.read_file(contourPath)
linestring = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)

print(contour.crs)
# # Reproject both geometries to EPSG:4326
contour = contour.to_crs(epsg=32645)
linestring = linestring.to_crs(epsg=32645)

intersections = linestring.intersection(contour)
# Check if any intersections were found
if not intersections.empty:
    print("Intersections found between linestring and contour.")
    intersections.to_file('intersections.shp', crs=contour.crs)
else:
    print("No intersections found. There might be gaps or misalignments.")
```

The code is not able to find intersections and returns empty LINESTRING. However, it is quite evident in the below image that both these vectors are intersecting at least at 3 points. Also, I am getting a warning `geopandas\base.py:31: UserWarning: The indices of the two GeoSeries are different.`

Why is the intersection list is empty?

## Extract one point from the LineString geometry`

[image: Picture showing intersection of contour and line at 3 points]

Comment: If you are sure that the code is correct and the result us null can you make sure that if the CRS is the same?

Comment: In this line I have made the CRS same
`contour = contour.to_crs(epsg=32645)
linestring = linestring.to_crs(epsg=32645)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gpd.overlay` with `keep_geom_type=False`:

```
import geopandas as gpd

contour = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\contour.shp")
river = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\rivers.shp")
river = river.to_crs(contour.crs)

#i = contour.intersection(river)
# i.unique()
# <GeometryArray>
# [<LINESTRING Z EMPTY>]

i2 = gpd.overlay(df1=contour, df2=river, how="intersection", keep_geom_type=False)
# i2.geometry.head(2)
# 0    POINT (431730.187 6370770.016)
# 1    POINT (431227.744 6370352.271)

ax = contour.plot(linewidth=1, edgecolor="gray", figsize=(20,20))
river.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=1.5, edgecolor="blue")
i2.plot(ax=ax, markersize=100, marker="o", color="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked, can you please explain or guide me to some tutorial about it. Thanks

Comment: Nice! See: [Set operations with overlay](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/set_operations.html). Intersecting two line layers will result in points if the lines doesnt align exactly.